# Can we go back to our own varna dharma?

Tags: scripture, vedas, caste-system, samskara, upanayanam

If our Brahmin or Kshatriya ancestors did not perform Upanayana Samskara and have not followed their dharma can we still have rights to get Upanayana Samskara for ourselves and our children?
If no, any prayaschitta measures are mentioned in the texts?

Comment: Yes you may still have the right depending on how many generations have not performed Upanayana .. you should consult  local purohits to see what they have to say .. There are prayschittas given in the scriptures for such cases.

Comment: See -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24137/4732